# Having trouble with code - Deleting records from database - JS / PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm having some trouble with this code pinpointing exactly where the problems coming from, I'm not sure if theres a problem with the javascript but when I go to select a record from select.php it just ends up stalling.. (nothing happens ;/)

**confirmDelete.js**

```
function fnConfirm(delUrl) {
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {
window.location = delUrl;
}

var linkDel = document.getElementById("linkDelete");

linkDel.onclick= fnConfirm;
```

**select.php**

```
<?php header("Cache-Control:no-cache"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Delete Cabin -AdminPanel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="confirmDelete.js"></script>
  <h2>Select from the cabins listed below to delete:</h2>

  <?php

    //connect to server and database
     include 'sqldb_connect.inc.php';

    //set up query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblCabins";

     //execute query
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(!$result)
    {
        mysql_close();
        exit("Error retrieving cabins from database");
    }

    //get the number of rows in the cabins table and store in a variable
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) <1)
    {
        mysql_close();
        exit("No cabin entries found");
    }

    //start table
  ?>
<!--.......................................................................-->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>cabinID</th>
            <th>Cabin Type</th>
            <th>Cabin Description</th>
            <th>Price per night</th>
            <th>Price per week</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
<!--.......................................................................-->
  <?php

        //fetch the next row (or record) of the result set until there are no more left
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            //store the results in variables
            $cabinID = $row['cabinID'];
            $cabintype = $row['cabinType'];
            $cabindesc = $row['cabinDescription'];
            $pricepern = $row['pricePerNight'];
            $priceperw = $row['pricePerWeek'];
            $photo = $row['PHOTO'];
  ?>
<!--.......................................................................-->
            <tr>
                <td><?= $cabinID; ?></td>
                <td><?= $cabintype; ?></td>
                <td><?= $cabindesc; ?></td>
                <td><?= $pricepern; ?></td>
                <td><?= $priceperw; ?></td>
                <td><?= $photo; ?></td>
                <td><a id="linkDelete" href="javascript:fnConfirm('cabinDelete_process.php?cabinID=<?= "$cabinID"; ?>')">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
<!--.................................................................................-->        
  <?php 
        }
        mysql_close(); 
  ?>
<!--.................................................................................-->  
    </table>  

</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php header("Cache-Control:no-cache"); ?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>deleteCabinProcess - adminPanel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <?php
        //this page will delete the cabin 
        //selected from the previous page

        //read cabinID passed to this page
        $cabinID = $_GET['cabinID'];

        //connect to server and database
        include 'sqldb_connect.inc.php';

        //set up query
        $query = "DELETE FROM tblCabins WHERE cabinID = '$cabinID'";

        //execute query
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if(!$result)
        {
            mysql_close();
            exit("Error deleting Cabin from the database");
        }

        mysql_close();
        exit ("Successfully deleted the record from the database ");    
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can see any problems it'd be greatly appreciated.. Brb need to go outside and adjust my eyes!

Comment: You're adding `fnConfirm` to the links twice, once as the `href` and once as the `onclick`. I'd start by getting rid of one of those. Also, your links shouldn't all have the same ID - IDs should be unique in the page. That will be causing problems for `getElementById`. Use a class instead.

Comment: if the confirm-box pops up, the problem is in the Server-Side-Code, if not the HTML / Javascript is causing the problem. as robjingram wrote, you are calling the function twice. i think you could leave the `linkDel.onclick= fnConfirm;` part way.